# Trouble with writing a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, mysqli

I have a table for a game that keeps track of loans taken out in the game.  The game can't read time stamps, so I'm having to use an increment based system for telling how much time has passed before taking out the next loan payment.  Basically the server restarts 6 times a day, so using a column in the table to keep track of restarts makes sure the player only get's deducted their loan payment 1 time per day in the game (otherwise it'll deduct it every restart, which will break the player's bank).  To achieve this, I want to have a stored procedure that the server will run at startup to increment the table to keep track of who should make a payment on the next restart cycle.  Most everything is controlled in game except for setting these values in the table.

The table columns:

```
id | active | balance | count | due | flags | default
```

So here is the logic for the stored procedure, it should run on all rows.  Except I've never written a stored procedure nor am sure how to have it apply to all rows based on conditions.  Here is the logic:

```
if active != 0 then continue with the below actions
if due == 0 and count > 1 then set count - 1
if due == 0 and count == 1 then set count = 6 and due = 1
if due == 1 then set count = 6
if balance  == 0 then set due = 0 and count = 0 and active = 0
```

I want that to run on all columns.  The game will handle deducting the balance from the player's bank (another table) so long as due == 1 and then set due = 0.  It will also handle inserting the initial loan and setting all the values to default to start the above process on the next restart.  Then the stored procedure will take care of the rest, so if their balance is 0 it will deactivate the loan and zero out all values.  But if it's active it'll increment the server restart count for that player and also set due flag if 6 restarts has gone by, then restart the whole thing after the player pays in game and the game set's due = 0.

I'm not the greatest with SQL let alone stored procedures, especially with an entire table.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you pretty close.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_theProcedure]
AS
BEGIN
UPDATE theTable
SET due = CASE WHEN balance = 0 THEN 0 WHEN (due = 0 AND [count] = 1) THEN 1 ELSE due END,
    [count] = CASE WHEN balance = 0 THEN 0 WHEN (due = 0 AND [count] = 1) OR due = 1 THEN 6 WHEN (due = 0 AND [count] > 1) THEN [count] - 1 ELSE [count] END,
    active = CASE WHEN balance = 0 THEN 0 ELSE active END
WHERE active <> 0
END
```

Comment: Here is what I get:  MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[count] = 1) THEN 1 ELSE due END, [count] = CASE WHEN balance = 0 THEN 0 WH' at line 3

Comment: Try removing the brackets. MySQL might not like them.

Comment: just needed to add a ; before end, Ill test the functionality tonight and let  you know how it turns out